# How does range() allocate memory in Python 3?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, range

I'm a beginner programmer, and I took a class in C and got (what I believe and hope to be) a really good understanding of how different functions and data types allocate memory differently.

So, with that in mind, could someone explain how `range()` in Python uses memory, please?

I know `range()` in Python 2 would create a list of values, so that's pretty straightforward to understand, but in Python 3, I keep seeing people say it "creates a new object" or makes an "iterator object", but what does the computer do internally with regards to memory?

Also, from what I understand, for-loops work the way for-each loops work in Java, so how does a function like `for n in range(6)` work if it's not iterating through a list of 6 numbers from 0-5?

Just to be clear, I know that, as a beginner, memory usage shouldn't be a concern, but I just like knowing how things work under the hood.

Comment: What it does internally with regard to memory is: allocates a dozen or so bytes, and puts an iterator object there. If you don't understand iterators, then you're asking the wrong question :)

Comment: My confusion came from learning how to use for-loops to iterate through lists or strings, so naturally, I assumed range() also created a list, and the for-loop iterated through that list. However, if range() doesn't create a list, what does the for-loop "iterate" through then? Is it comparing a condition now? That was my thought process, so I hoped a "memory-focused approach" would help.

Comment: A range is essentially a 3-tuple with special iteration behavior, not a variable-sized container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python 3 [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) object does not allocate memory by creating it (other than the heap memory allocated by itself object, of course); it is a [sequence object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence). All it contains is the start, stop and step values.

It 'generates' numbers on demand, in this case, the 'demand' is the loop `for n in range(6):`. As you 'iterate' over the object the next integer is calculated each iteration.

The `range` object returns an iterator when called `__iter__()`. The `for` loop automatically calls this function.

We can get the next value by calling `next()` to it. For example:

```py
r = range(6)
i = r.__iter__()

print(next(i))  # 0
print(next(i))  # 1
print(next(i))  # 2
print(next(i))  # 3
print(next(i))  # 4
print(next(i))  # 5
print(next(i))  # raises 'StopIteration'
```

The loop automatically stops when `next()` raises `StopIteration`.

A possible implementation would be as:

```py
def range_func(stop):
    i = 0
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

*Note: This is not the real implementation of `range`; The real one is way more complicated than this.*

The above function does not allocate any memory for all of the numbers that it generates. It can be used like `range()`.

```py
for n in range_func(6):
    print(n)
```

Comment: Generally agree, nice explanation.  However this “The above function does not allocate any memory” is inaccurate.  Where does the function sit on the stack, (along with its variable! and return (link) instructions, etc.) if no memory is allocated?  Please consider rephrasing this.

Comment: Any question of memory allocation is an implementation detail. An answer that might apply to how CPython implements object creation may be entirely irrelevant to another implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You say: "I know range() in Python 2 would create a list of values" - you probably shouldn't be using Python 2 at this stage, but [it did](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) unless you were using [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) in Python 2.7.

What's important to realise though is that Python has many different implementations, that don't need to do the same thing "under the hood", they just need to be correct implementations of the language. As commenters have pointed out, such an implementation may change over time as well, so the differences aren't even limited to specific implementations, but could exist between versions of the same.

How it works for CPython (which is likely the implementation you're using, as it is easily the most common) is explained in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range :

> The advantage of the range type over a regular list or tuple is that a range object will always take the same (small) amount of memory, no matter the size of the range it represents (as it only stores the start, stop and step values, calculating individual items and subranges as needed).

You also say: "I just like knowing how things work under the hood" - the whole point of using a higher order language is often that you don't need to know exactly what's going on under the hood. It should be sufficient to know that `range()` is a very efficient way to get access to a range of values while having a small memory footprint and good performance, definitely when compared to the alternative like creating a list, or writing a generator in Python to do the same.

Having said that, implementations can have interesting side-effects that you may count on, but that change over time. It can be worth knowing how the implementation of some language feature causes such side effects, and whether they are likely to change. Code written for Python 2.7's `range` may no longer work for 3.0, if it relied on something specific to the `list` type. Instead of learning about every little detail of a language though, you're better off keeping an eye on the changelog for major version changes. Like here https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists

"how does a function like `for n in range(6)` work" - that's not a *function* but it works because a range is an iterable and `for` can thus iterate over its contents from start to finish. You could replace `range(6)` with any iterable and `for` would still work.

Comment: Also, in a broader sense, 'what goes on under the hood' is not guaranteed always to be the same as CPython is further developed.

Comment: "I don't think that's entirely true" - It is. Python2 `range(...)` is equivalent in effect to Python3 `list(range(...))`, while Python3 `range(...)` equivalent was the confusingly named `xrange(...)`. Though, as you say, it is an obsolete knowledge, except in few niches.

Comment: “… as CPython is further developed” and considering the implementation-specific details.

Comment: @Amadan you're right, I didn't go back and check when I wrote that, but after having a quick look just now I realise I remembered `xrange` as being part of `range`, when it was a seperate function in Python 2.7. I'm updating the answer to reflect that.